# How can I edit the "Account" block in my footer?

Tags: magento-1.9, footer

I can't find the cms page for it. The block contains :

MY ACCOUNT
ORDERS AND RETURNS

as links and I want to add a link and change the title of "Accounts". What do I have to do?

Comment: try this in your footr block <li><a title="My Accoubt" href="{{store url='customer/account'}}">My Account</a>

Answer (score 0):

Create static block and add below code

```
<ul>    
<li><a title="My Accoubt" href="{{store url='customer/account'}}">My Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add `local.xml`

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">

        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>Static block id here</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go admin side on top menu : CMS -> Static Blocks and click on "Footer Links" after add your links in section "Content *"

For eg.

```
<ul>
 <li> {{if="about-magento-demo-store"}}<a href="{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer/accoun"}}">My account</a> <a href="{{store url='customer/account'}}">My account</a></li>
 <li><a href="{{store direct_url="sales/guest"}}">ORDERS AND RETURNS</a> <a href="{{store url='sales/guest'}}">ORDERS AND RETURNS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the links you mean are the following folder

```
\app\design\frontend\default\themeXXXX\
```

The Order and Return link is in **layout/sales.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
   <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
     <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

The Sitemap link you can find here:**layout/catalog.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
</reference>
```

The Search terms link you can find here: 
**layout/catalogsearch.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
        <label>Search Terms</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
        <title>Search Terms</title>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
        <label>Advanced Search</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The contacts link in:
**layout/contacts.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
</reference>
```

Just comment the ones out you want to remove. If you want to remove all of them and just add your static cms block "footer_links" then you will need to copy this file `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php` to your local files and comment the following piece of code out

```
$this->getLinks();
```